Spacy matching countries in messy data
I have some natural language text that I am trying to parse using spacy but having a hard time getting this to cover all possible variations.
Data is basically a set of recommendations for a set of countries, embedded together in a single text block. I want to extract the list of countries and their associated recommendations.
For example:
Consider implementing the recommendations of the Special Rapporteur on violence against women and CEDAW (India) (Thailand), and France recommends to strengthen measures to increase the participation by ethnic minority women in line with CEDAW recommendations, and consider intensifying human rights education (Ghana).   

Should be processed into 2 lists:
states = [["india", "thailand"], ["ghana"]]
recommendations = ["Consider implementing the recommendations of the Special Rapporteur on violence against women and CEDAW", "France recommends to strengthen measures to increase the participation by ethnic minority women in line with CEDAW recommendations, and consider intensifying human rights education"]

So far I have been getting away with a custom sentence segmentation in spacy but this is growing out of hand to handle lots of edge cases such as countries appearing in the form (Country1, Country2 and Country3) or sometimes missing parenthesis or typos in countries. Some countries can also have very different spellings, like iran, islamic republic of iran, iran (islamic republic of), iran, islamic republic of.
Looking for some guidance on what a proper way would be to handle this. I Was thinking using spacy's Matcher but it wasn't clear how to apply it to such a use case.

IMHO I would suggest an approach that includes the use of pycountry library.
This includes ISO country encoding with a set of common/official names.
Example
>>> import pycountry
>>> pycountry.countries.get(common_name='Iran')
Country(alpha_2='IR', alpha_3='IRN', common_name='Iran', flag='', name='Iran, Islamic Republic of', numeric='364', official_name='Islamic Republic of Iran')

The creation of a set of dictionaries that retrieves the information from this library together with a regex approach I think it might do the trick.

Furthermore the pycountry does have a nice fuzzy matching algorithm
Fuzzy matching
>>> pycountry.countries.search_fuzzy('Islamic Republic of Iran')
[Country(alpha_2='IR', alpha_3='IRN', common_name='Iran', flag='', name='Iran, Islamic Republic of', numeric='364', official_name='Islamic Republic of Iran')]

